# Simple control panel for starting/stopping AWS instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EBS-root server at AWS that the service desk staff use for infrequent tasks, and I only want it to be turned on when they need it.

I would like the service desk to be able to go a web page that says

```
                              [Start the server]
```

Clicking that button will start the server, and set a CNAME to whatever address it comes up to  using Amazon Route 53.  This page could either prompt for a username and password, or have a hard coded IAM account.

Extra for experts would be if this system handled stopping the server after a programmable number of hours.

Before I write this - I expect the JS SDK would mean that the simple case can be done in a single web page - has anyone else written this or seen something that could do it?

Comment: By the way were you able to develop it?

Answer (score 0):

Eric Hammond has some suggestions about using AWS auto-scaling to run instances on a schedule [here](http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance)

I would avoid creating DNS records, because of the time it takes for changes to propagate and inconsistent DNS server caching behavior.

Consider using an Elastic IP and registering an A record for that IP. When the instance starts, assign the IP to it (could do this in a cloud-init/user-data script). You'll pay a small per-hour charge for the EIP when not attached, but it's much less than per-hour instance charges.

I think the service desk web page could potentially be created with only browser-based JavaScript code,but you have to watch out for the limitations browsers put on cross-site scripting. I've not seen anything like this.

If you have some server/host that is running constantly, you could use it to handle starting and stopping the instances. I've previously run a small utility that would monitor an email inbox for messages that would trigger starting or stopping EC2 instances. If you have a cheap web host with shell access, you could set up a cron script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Try exploring services like [RightScale](http://www.RightScale.com), [Ylastic](http://ylastic.com/), etc. Some amount of customization and ACL has to be done for what you are asking.
2. Custom develop a simple webapp using [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/). There are options for Ruby, Java, .NET, etc. There is a service side JS framework [here](https://github.com/livelycode/aws-lib)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it's just been bumped up.

If use is regular you could use [AWS instance scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/). Sounds like it's not though.

A really simple way to achieve this would be to have a batch file on a shared drive that they can double click. It should have something like this in it that sets up the [CLI environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) and [starts the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html)

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AYIAIW6G6JMJKBADF
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ABC123ABC123
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

Downside is you might need the AWS CLI installed on each PC, but you might manage to put it in the same folder as the batch file... maybe. Or let them RDP into a server. It's not as convenient, but if it's occasional use maybe it's good enough. Even just have one PC with it installed they can walk up to.

You will need the access keys to be associated with a user that has very limited rights. Lock down the user with a profile that lets them have permissions to run th[e start-instances API call. You might find you need a few other allowed calls, but this suggests that should be enough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_tag-owner.html). [Another](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) suggests you might need to grant iam:PassRole

Have a batch file run every night that turns the instance off using the [stop-instances command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html).

This is less elegant that a web page, but much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**You've already somewhat answered your own question.**

> You can do this very easily with any SDK, and you had already named the **JS SDK** so I assume you would lean towards JS.

I'm not a web developer but have written many scripts that control EC2 and R53 (as well as other aws services) using Go/Python but **at the end of the day it's a trivial task no matter the toolset**...

Here is an overall workflow to get you started:

1. Collect user action, collect current instance state
2. Start/Stop based on user action
3. If it was a start action, harvest the public IP and update the dns record (R53)

---

Here is some docs and examples to work from:

**Using the `AWS.EC2` class, you can call `startInstance()`**

> Starts a specified instance.

`startInstance()` Doc: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/OpsWorks.html#startInstance-property

**For DNS, use `AWS.Route53` class and call `changeResourceRecordSets()`:**

> Creates, changes, or deletes a resource record set

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#changeResourceRecordSets-property

---

For the **scheduled task that shuts down the server after X hours**. You again would need to develop this, but this would be your flow. This script would need to run either in Lambda or as a cron job on a server (*or the server itself since it's stop only!!!*)

1. Gather start time of the instance
2. Get now time
3. If start time < now() - interval *X* hours, stop the instance.

Methods related to these tasks: 
`ec2.describeInstances()` `ec2.stopInstance()`

---

**Here is there example library:**

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascript/example_code

Here is a snippet from the above example set:

```
// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// Instead of params, you can use the user input from your page. 
var params = { 
  InstanceIds: [process.argv[3]],
  DryRun: true
};

if (process.argv[2].toUpperCase() === "START") {
  // Call EC2 to start the selected instances
  ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err && err.code === 'DryRunOperation') {
      params.DryRun = false;
      ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
          } else if (data) {
            console.log("Success", data.StartingInstances);
          }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("You don't have permission to start instances.");
    }
  });
} else if (process.argv[2].toUpperCase() === "STOP") {
  // Call EC2 to stop the selected instances
  ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err && err.code === 'DryRunOperation') {
      params.DryRun = false;
      ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
          } else if (data) {
            console.log("Success", data.StoppingInstances);
          }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("You don't have permission to stop instances");
    }
  });
}
```